# Stripe Annual Subscription: How to credit user's account every month?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment, subscription, billing

I'm building a micro-SaaS and I need to renew my users' credits every month depending on their subscription.

If they choose a monthly subscription plan, I can receive the `invoice.paid` event every month and add credits to their account.

But what if they choose an annual plan? Is there a way to receive a monthly event from Stripe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use an annual Stripe Subscription there's no way to get monthly events from Stripe.  Stripe only generates Events when things happen on Stripe's end, and for an annual Subscription nothing happens on Stripe's end every month.

You would need to set up a scheduled task on your end instead.